# Rails3 - Edit and show a bill after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to create an "Adherent" (like a member for a non-profit organisation), with two submit buttons.
The first only create the "adherent", and the second "create the adherent and show a bill" (because adherent have to pay).

I'm using Ajax.

So I have : AdherentsController and FactureAdhesionController . 
My problem is that I can't show the bill after created the adherent.

Log :

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `nom_adherent' for nil:NilClass):
    2: 
    3: 
    4: 
    5: <%= @facture_adhesion.nom_adherent %>
  app/views/facture_adhesions/_show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_facture_adhesions__show_html_erb__741033609_23539632'
  app/controllers/adherents_controller.rb:141:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/adherents_controller.rb:135:in `create'
```

AdherentsController

```
def create
    @adherent = Adherent.new(params[:adherent])

     # if params[:commit] == "Valider" do things

      elsif params[:commit] == 'Valider et éditer une facture'  #si on a cliqué sur "valider et voir la facture"
        if @adherent.save
            @facture = FactureAdhesion.new(
                :date_adhesion => @adherent.date_adhesion,
                :dimension_date_id => num_aujourdhui,
                :nom_adherent => @adherent.nom,
                :prenom_adherent => @adherent.prenom,
                :adresse1 => @adherent.adresse1,
                :adresse2 => @adherent.adresse2,
                :code_postal => @adherent.code_postal,
                :ville => @adherent.ville,
                :telephone => @adherent.numero_telephone,
                :adresse_mail => @adherent.adresse_mail,
                :montant => @adherent.type_tarif.montant,
                :libelle => "Adhesion"              
            )

            respond_to do |format|
                if @facture.save
                    format.html { redirect_to @adherent, notice: 'Adherent was successfully created.' }
                    format.json { render json: @adherent, status: :created, location: @adherent }
                    format.js do
                    render :inline => affichage_sur_panneau_principal + '$("#panneau_principal").html("<%= j (render(:partial => "facture_adhesions/show", :locals => {:facture_adhesion => @facture}))  %>");' + gerer_loading
                    end
                else
                    format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.json { render json: @adherent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.js {render :inline => '$("#panneau_principal").html("<%= j (render(:partial => "adherents/new"))  %>")'}
                end
            end
        end

      end
```

FactureAdhesions/show

```
<%= @facture_adhesion.nom_adherent %>
```

The Facture is well created, but I can't show it. I think the problem is that `@facture_adhesion` is empty. But how can I get it from FactureAdhesion/show ? `:locals =>` seems not to work...

Does somebody has an idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you are trying to render expects a variable **@facture_adhesion** to be declared.

Whether the view is render via the show action (default behavior) or via another action, the variable must be declared somehow.

So in your create action you must assign a **@facture_adhesion** variable with a valid value in order to be used by the view. In your code snippet, this declaration is not present.

Comment: Thank you Grotori. I thought passing the variable in :locals did the job... But now it works !  Thanks again